# Projeto não consegue resolver o mscorlib para o Framework .NET 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho um projeto C# Windows Form que usa o Framework 4.5.2. Comprei um notebook novo e estou tentando executar esse projeto, porém ao tentar executar não aparece nenhum erro e mesmo assim o projeto não é construído. Acessei as propriedades do projeto e quando clico em Services ou Settings aparece a mensagem:

```
Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.  This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted.
```

Essa versão do Framework está instalada na minha máquina. Eu já criei um projeto de teste usando essa versão do Framework e roda normal.
Como posso resolver esse problema do projeto não conseguir resolver o mscorlib?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema. Cliquei em Reference e vi que a referência Microsoft.Office.Core estava com um ponto de interrogação, então à removi. Cliquei para adicionar novamente a referência e adicionei novamente a Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library, que é a que corresponde ao Microsoft.Office.Core. Após adicionar, compilei a aplicação e executou normal.